# How to pass a username containing @ as a parameter

Tags: oracle, networking, plsql, configuration, oracle12c

I`m trying to open up for REST API-calls from PL/SQL in an Oracle database, and to do this, I need my user to be able to perform network calls.

After a bit of research, I believe the following approach should work:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
        host => '*',
        ace => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('connect'),
                           principal_name => 'my-user@my-domain',
                           principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
END;
```

...and it *does seem* to work so long as `my-user` is a single / simple name, such as 'my-user'; The problem occurs when trying to apply this to a username containing an `@`, as in the example above.

In such cases, I get the error:

> ORA-44003: invalid SQL name

When comparing a user containing `@` in his username with one without it, the only obvious difference I can see it that the former has `Authentication Type = EXTERNAL`, whereas the latter has `Authentication Type = PASSWORD`, but I can't see why that should matter.

Rather it seems to me like this might be a syntax-related issue - can anyone either confirm or deny this, and point out the correct way to pass in the `principal` parameter in a case like this?

Answer (score 2):

The principal is always a database user, so it can't have a @ in the name anyway. You need to specify the database user that will be executing the REST calls on behalf of the end user.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm finding this a little confusing though: When I try to run an http-query using the `@`-user, I get an error: "*network access denied by access control list (ACL)*". This is the same error I got earlier for the other user, which now has access. Is the limited access not related to the `@`-user then? And if the `@`-user`s query is in effect run by another user, then how can I identify which user that is?

Comment: Not sure - maybe the REST calls are being executed by an ORDS account?

Comment: ACL problems can be debugged with this:

with aclprivs as (
  select
    P.principal, N.acl, P.privilege, P.is_grant, P.invert,
    N.host, N.lower_port, N.upper_port,
    X.shared, X.security_class_name, X.security_class_ns, X.description
  from dba_network_acl_privileges P, dba_network_acls N, xds_acl x
  where P.aclid = N.aclid
   and N.aclid = X.aclid(+)
) select * from aclprivs
  where principal = '...user...'
  order by acl, privilege;

Comment: You'll need to substitute in the relevant user in the principal clause.  Access to external host/ports must be done for every user that attempts it.